# external jars error no class definiton found on wildfly

Tags: eclipse, jar, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I have an EJB project which is using some external jars i.e.  JasperReports and poi.jars (for excel workbook read-write) now when ever I deploy my project on wildfly I get an error:

```
no class definiton found for net/sf/jasperreports/buildreport/
```

How can I solve this I tried creating modules in the following directory

```
module/system/layers/base/com/
```

and then in my projects manifest I put them in the Dependencies tag, but it didn't work

what I am currently doing is extracting jars and placing them in my deployment and when I redepoly the project the error is removed but I don't want to do it this way, I want to know the standard way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution on a forum here is the Link:

[Blog](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html)!